# Heroku error: "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306" when trying to deploy Express + React application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I was trying to deploy my Express + React application to Heroku. Heroku connected successfully with my Github account, then clicking "Deploy Branch" led to "Your app was successfully deployed". But when I went to view my website, it showed:

"Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details".

Here are my logs:

```
Starting process with command `npm start`
> myproject@ start /app
> node backend/index.js
My project SQL server listening on PORT 4000
/app/backend/index.js:22
if (err) throw err;
^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
```

And the `index.js` which connects to MySQL:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('go to /my-project to see my project')
});

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'myjs123@',
    database: 'my-project',
    debug: false
});

pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    app.get('/my-project', (req, res) => {
        connection.query(SELECT_ALL_FACTS_QUERY, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err)
            }
            else {
                return res.json({
                    data: results
                })
            };
        });
    });

});

const SELECT_ALL_FACTS_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM `my-project`.`my-table`;';

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('My project SQL server listening on PORT 4000');
});
```

What did I do wrong and how could I deploy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It passed this stage after I removed `if (err) throw err;`, still not sure why this happened.

Nithin's answer was taken into account too.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the below code the localhost should not be used, the localhost will not work in deployment.

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    //here
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'myjs123@',
    database: 'my-project',
    debug: false
});
```

And another mistake I found is you should use an environment variable to store
port numbers. In production, the port number is assigned by Heroku, if not assigned you
can assign. So your code should be

```
let port=process.env.PORT||4000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port} `);
});
```

Comment: Should I just remove `host: 'localhost'` or should I change it something else?

Comment: You should change to something else. In deployment, there should be remote MySQL database service (localhost will not work). I think you created it, If not then create one. This video might help you.  [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBCH9OTVaGw)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add (add-ons) to your heroku account
and connect it to your app.
For example, you can use (JAWS_DB mysql)

By having the following code in your connection:

```
// import the Sequelize constructor from the library
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
require('dotenv').config();

let sequelize;

// when deployed on Heroku
if (process.env.JAWSDB_URL) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.JAWSDB_URL);
} else {
    // localhost
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, 
    process.env.DB_USER, 
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        port: 3306
    });
}

module.exports = sequelize;
```

Answer (score 0):

the same errorhappened to me while i was trying to connect to heroku cli and i jus read the heroku config for proxy and that was the case. problem solved by configuring the http and https proxy like

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber
```

or  set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:portnumber